# Re-balancing a red-black tree after inserting not working. (C++)

Tags: c++, insert, nodes, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I'm working on my C++ university assignment, and I have a problem with re-balancing a red-black tree after inserting a node in it. Everything works when inserting a root node, but once I insert more than the root node, the program crashes. This bug is driving me crazy and it's probably some silly mistake as I'm VERY new to C++.

It also works perfectly if I comment out the 2nd, 4th and 5th if statements in the putHelper function. I'm thinking the problem is maybe because I'm dereferencing uninitialised pointers in those if statements, but I'm not really sure, and if that is the case, how would I go about fixing it?

I'm posting relevant code snippets below, but if anyone wants to try running the code, I can post that too. It's very much a work in progress which hasn't been tested much yet (and I still need to code a remove function).

This is the header file, data.h:
http://pastebin.com/Fr1SKERV

And this is the main tester file, main.cpp:
http://pastebin.com/UxKRaG53

Here are relevant code snippets:

Node class declaration (K and V are generic variables):

```
class Node
{
    public:
        K key; // The index of the node.
        V value; // The value of the node.
        Node *right; // A pointer to the right subtree.
        Node *left; // A pointer to the left subtree.
        bool isRed; // TRUE if the node is red and FALSE if the node is black.

        Node(K key, V value) // Constructor.
        {
            this->key = key;
            this->value = value;
            this->right = 0;
            this->left = 0;
            this->isRed = true;
        }
};
```

Main insert function:

```
template<typename K, typename V> void Map<K, V>::put(K key, V value) // Function to insert a new node to the tree.
{
    root = putHelper(root, key, value);
    root->isRed = false;

    size++;
}
```

Insert helper function:

```
template<typename K, typename V> typename Map<K, V>::Node *Map<K, V>::putHelper(Node *x, K key, V value) // Recursive helper function for put that traverses the tree and inserts a new node at the proper position, after which it balances the tree.
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
        return new Node(key, value); // If the position for the new node was found...
    }

    if ((x->left->isRed) && (x->right->isRed)) // If both children nodes are red...
    {
        flipColour(x);
    }

    if (key == x->key) // If the key is already in use...
    {
        x->value = value; // Update the node with the new value.
    }
        else if (key < x->key)
        {
            x->left = putHelper(x->left, key, value); // Move to the left child.
        }
            else
            {
                x->right = putHelper(x->right, key, value); // Move to the right child.
            }

    if (x->right->isRed) // If the child node to the right of the parameter node is red...
    {
        x = rotateLeft(x);
    }

    if ((x->left->isRed) && (x->left->left->isRed)) // If the child node to the left of the parameter node and the child node to the left of that are both red...
    {
        x = rotateRight(x);
    }

    return x;
}
```

Red-black tree balancing functions (flip colour and rotate):

```
template<typename K, typename V> void Map<K, V>::flipColour(Node *x) // Function to flip the colour of a node and its two children.
{
    x->isRed        = !x->isRed; // Flip the colour of the parameter node.
    x->left->isRed  = !x->left->isRed; // Flip the colour of the left child node.
    x->right->isRed = !x->right->isRed; // Flip the colour of the right child node.
}

template<typename K, typename V> typename Map<K, V>::Node *Map<K, V>::rotateLeft(Node *x) // Function to rotate a set of three nodes to the left.
{
    Node *y = x->right; // Create a new node from the parameter node's right child node.
    x->right = y->left;
    y->left = x;
    y->isRed = y->left->isRed;
    y->left->isRed = true; // Set the new node's left child node to red.

    return y;
}

template<typename K, typename V> typename Map<K, V>::Node *Map<K, V>::rotateRight(Node *x) // Function to rotate a set of three nodes to the right.
{
    Node *y = x->left; // Create a new node from the parameter node's left child node.
    x->left = y->right;
    y->right = x;
    y->isRed = y->right->isRed;
    y->right->isRed = true; // Set the new node's right child node to red.

    return y;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as the deadline for this assignment is approaching soon! Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This isn't a great question for StackOverflow. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: Where and how it crashes??

Comment: I would say that the code crashes here: `if ((x->left->isRed) && (x->right->isRed))` in `putHelper` as `left` and `right` may be `nullptr`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. As I said, it crashes when I insert my second node into the tree, so in the putHelper function. It just says "redBlack.exe has stopped working" in a popup dialogue.

admdrew, I think I'm missing something, since I'm not sure why this isn't a suitable question. Sorry if it isn't though!

Comment: Jarod42, yeah that's what I was thinking too... but how would I go about fixing that? That code's the same as implementation I found on the internet, and somehow it works for them haha.

Comment: @Step it looks like your next step is to learn how to walk through your code with a debugger.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know where the problem is, but I'm simply not sure how to go about fixing it. It's probably a simple fix, but you'll have to be patient with me, since like I said I'm still very inexperienced in C++ I'm afraid!